# Binding using Ninject WithConstructorArgument which is an interface

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I have a class like this that uses interfaces

```
public class CouchbaseCache : ICouchbaseCache, IDistributedCache
{
    public CouchbaseCache(ICouchbaseCacheBucketProvider provider, 
          IOptions<CouchbaseCacheOptions> options)
    {
        Options = options.Value;
        Bucket = provider.GetBucket();
    }
}


public interface ICouchbaseCacheBucketProvider : INamedBucketProvider
{
}

public interface INamedBucketProvider
{
    string BucketName { get; }

    IBucket GetBucket();
}
```

I am trying to bind using Ninject by giving constructor arguments and I understand if its a string as parameter I would do (“provider”, “something here”) but how would I bind it if the constructor parameter is an interface? Any direction on this?

```
 Bind<IDistributedCache>().To<CouchbaseCache> . 
().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("provider", ICouchbaseCacheBucketProvider);
```

Comment: Your example is missing the implementation of `ICouchbaseCacheBucketProvider`. How can it be instantiated and what is it's lifetime?

Comment: `ToMethod(ctx => new CouchbaseCache( ctx.Kernel.Get<ICouchbaseCacheBucketProvider >(),   ctx.Kernel.Get<IOptions<CouchbaseCacheOptions>>())` would probably work, provided you have registered the correct bindings. But, if so, I don't see the point as you would just be doing the job of the dependency resolver